# Heston - How important are the initial guess in calibration and if it is very important, what would be a good way to get initial guess?

Tags: heston, parameter

So I have been trying to implement a simple Heston calibration using crude MC with 10k scenarios and 1000 time steps and the best I could get is 3x of the observed implied volatility.

I suspect it has something to do with the way my initial guess worked, and therefore, I am just wondering:

1. Is the initial guess very critical (that a not-so-great initial guess could give you 3x the differences)
2. If it is, how can I get a good initial guess?

Comment: 3x sounds quite off, the initial guess should not get you that far away. Care to elaborate a bit on your setup. Maybe it is just a small issue. Matlab?

Comment: What happens if you set the initial guess (very) close to the correct answer? If that doesn't work I fear you have a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check your results, you might try "The Heston Model: A Practical Approach with Matlab Code" by Nimalin Moodley, http://math.nyu.edu/~atm262/fall06/compmethods/a1/nimalinmoodley.pdf , in particular the www.ingber.com open source C++ code for Adaptive Simulated Annealing (+ SWIG to wrap/parse it to the language you are using)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the used optimization algorithm, esp. whether they act locally or globally.

Just to give you some ideas:

1. Local (deterministic) algorithms (e.g. [gradient methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)): a good initial guess is crucial.
2. (Global) stochastic algorithms (e.g. [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing)): the initial guess is irrelevant.

You can find more here: [Heston’s Stochastic Volatility Model Implementation, Calibration and Some Extensions by Sergei Mikhailov, Ulrich Nögel](http://www.math.umn.edu/~bemis/IMA/MMI2008/calibrating_heston.pdf)